# Outlook keeps putting good email into Junk Folder

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

I've been having a problem ever since I upgraded from Outlook 07 to 10.  Outlook keeps putting good emails into the Junk folder.  I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to fix it.  When i get an email the From line looks something like this:

> Bundle of Holding
>   webmaster=bundleofholding.com@mail157.atl101.mcdlv.net; on behalf of;
>   Bundle of Holding webmaster@bundleofholding.com

The problem is the first part is different every time I get a mail from said address (This Part: `webmaster=bundleofholding.com@mail157.atl101.mcdlv.net`)

If I try to add the mail to my safe senders list, it adds the above address, and not the @bundleofholding.com address.  Since the first part changes every time I get an email from them, it's impossible to add them to my safe senders list.  I have tried to manually add the @bundleofholding.com address to my contacts list, but it makes no difference.  It seems to only scan the first part and dump it into Junk.

This only started happening with Outlook 2010.  And it's driving me crazy as there are quite a few emails I get that seem to be sent through some sort of proxy like I have above.  It currently dumps more good emails into Junk than bad ones and I'm getting tempted to turn it off.  I had to go in and manually take out about 100 of the proxy address's the other day as the list size was getting ridiculous and it doesn't make any difference anyway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is any part of the domain the same?  Because `mcdlv.net` would have to remain the same because thats the actual domain that is sending the email.

Comment: There are quite a few different ones looking at my list, but I'll give it a shot.  I thought I had tried that in the past but I've tried so many things I this point I can't remember.  Hopefully it will work.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is your email hosted by Exchange by any chance? There may be further options available if so.

Answer (score 1):

These emails are being sent to you via MailChimp, one of the world's largest email service providers (ESP).

MailChimp usually delivers mail from the mcsv.net domain, but it seems that they often use mcdlv.net as well.

As @Ramhound suggests, the simplest solution would be to add `@mcdlv.net` to your Safe Senders list. However, this is unlikely to work, as it needs to take into account all possible subdomains. Outlook doesn't appear to support the format `@*.mcdlv.net`

MailChimp themselves say:

> The workaround in Outlook is to go to Tools > Options > Preferences >
>   Junk Email > Safe Senders > Import File 
>   There you can import a .txt file of all our domains. Any email you send to your own Outlook, such
>   as tests for your campaigns, will be on your safe senders list. For
>   safety reasons, **you'll need to contact our live chat team for the
>   list.**

You can read [MailChimp's knowledgebase article](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/my-from-name-is-changing-causing-the-email-to-go-into-the-junk-folder/) (from a sender's perspective) for further information.

Seeing as you probably don't have a MailChimp account, you will find it difficult to contact them via live chat. Their contact details are [here](http://mailchimp.com/contact/).

**Caution: If you manage to whitelist all emails from `mcdlv.net`, be aware that this will whitelist emails from thousands of email senders who use MailChimp - not just one sender**

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook users I have found two options to correct this problem.  Option 1 is to create a rule in Outlook to look for specific words in the sender's address and then deliver them to a folder I specify.  I prefer this method as it allows the receiver to specify which emails from MailChimp they want delivered.  Option 2 is to get the .txt file of domains directly from MailChimp support.  Import that list to the Junk Safe Sender's list.  It is a very lengthy list, and will allow all emails from any sender at MailChimp to deliver emails to your specified folder location.